# Webpack can not resolve baseUrl in node modules package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

So I have a node package I am developing with typescript and react where I set the `baseUrl` in `tsconfig.json` to the `src` folder so I can use absolute paths like `src/module`. The application using this node package (also react) uses webpack and also has its own `tsconfig` so when I import this module and run `rpm run webpack`, I get this error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve src/module in /node_modules/path_to_module

I have tried to use path aliases and combine with [tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) but this packages seems to only work if the path configuration (tsconfig) and webpack config is within the project.

I understand the issue here is since the tsconfig in the node package is not same as tsconfig webpack would use when running, it won't point to the `baseUrl` in the package

So, is it possible for me to set `baseUrl` in `tsconfig` of a node package and run `rpm run webpack` in another project using the node package that webpack knows to use the `baseUrl` in packages in node_modules